# Hover event not working after append() div content

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am attempting to use jquery to append `.thumb` into another last div when click the `.button`

This is the jquery function:

```
$('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeOut();
});
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
$('.button').click(function() {
    $html = '<div class="thumb">';
    $html += '<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1979/social/50/wordpress.png" />';
    $html += '<div class="close">X</div>';
    $html += '</div>';
    $('.box').append($html);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UfyQq/

The obstacle I am facing with this code is that the appended div not obey the hover event or use click function on the `.close`

I would really appreciate some help here, thanks!

Comment: i think browser set the event for every element at start and if you append element after loading page it's not work correctly.better set hover event after creating new element or set hover for up level of created element

Comment: I used separate components, inclusion hover event, click function and `$.ajax`, thanks to reply!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the appended content doesn't exist when you attach the event listeners. use [jQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on the parent element to fix this.

[check this working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfyQq/4/)

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter','.thumb',function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeIn();
});

$('.box').on('mouseleave','.thumb',function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use delegation:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UfyQq/5/)

```
$('.box').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('.close').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('.close').fadeOut();
    }
}, '.thumb');

$('.box').on('click','.close',function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: How to use click function on the `.close`

Answer (score 0):

Alter:

```
$('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeOut();
});
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
$('.button').click(function() {
    $html = '<div class="thumb">';
    $html += '<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1979/social/50/wordpress.png" />';
    $html += '<div class="close">X</div>';
    $html += '</div>';
    $('.box').append($html);
});
```

To:

```
$('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeOut();
});
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
$('.button').click(function() {
    $html = '<div class="thumb">';
    $html += '<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1979/social/50/wordpress.png" />';
    $html += '<div class="close">X</div>';
    $html += '</div>';
    $('.box').append($html);
    $('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.close').fadeOut();
});
$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
});
});
```

That will attach the events once again.

Comment: This will attach the `.close` click event many times to the existing buttons.

Comment: Well i know, but that no memory swap cos its override the previous event listeners. -sure there is much beautiful solutions for that.

Comment: Yes, but i attach the `$.ajax` should not be used as a way solve the my problem. Thanks!